# Set of maps such that $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a covering space will be open in $C_S^r(M,N)$

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, covering-spaces

I am trying to do an exercise that is as follows :

> Let $M$ and $N$ be manifolds. The set of maps $f\in C_S^1(M,N)$ such that $f:M\rightarrow N$ is a covering space with the extra restriction that instead of local homeomorphisms we have local diffeomorphisms ,is an open set in $C_S^r(M,N)$.

Now my first idea to try and prove this would be to use the fact that if we have a local diffeomorphism $f: U\rightarrow V$ then the set of diffeomorphisms is open in $C_S^r(U,V)$, but then I realized I have the problem that $C_S^r(U,V)$ is not open in $C_S^r(M,N)$, so I needed to try another approach . I have been thinking about this but I haven't gotten anywhere useful. Any help with this is aprecciated, Thanks in advance.

Comment: The topology on $C^r$ is that the section of $r$-jets converges locally uniformly?

Comment: uniformly on compact sets, yes you can see it like that

Comment: And a diffeomorphism is smooth or just differentiable?

Comment: Regardless the sequence $f_n:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that is sends $x\mapsto x$ on $[-n,n]$ and smoothly interpolates to the constant maps $x\mapsto n+1$ resp $x\mapsto -(n+1)$ outside of $[-n,n]$ will converge uniformly on compacta to the identity map and all its derivatives will do so as well. So complement of covering maps is not closed.